# How to flash custom ROM together with modem and bootloader without odin or heimdal?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, linux, twrp

I want to flash the "newest" SimplRom (v5F) on a Galaxy Note 4 and the [instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/note-4/snapdragon-dev/rom-simplrom-v1-t3004628) say I need to also flash the modem and bootloader firmware at the same time.

Now I have three files: `BL_N910FXXU1COI3.tar.md5`, `CP_modemCOI3.tar.md5` and `SimpLite_v5.zip` but I'm not sure how to flash them.

Most instructions tell me to use **Odin**, some describe the procedure using **Heimdall**. Odin is not an option for me (no Windows) and Heimdall seems to change it's user interface every now and then, so the instructions don't apply.

To make it short: is there a way to just use *TWRP*  or *dd* ([this](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote4qualcomm.html) worked for TWRP) to flash the files? I've found a lot of instructions but since there are so many different file types, recovery roms, devices, tools etc. out none of the instructions seem to apply for me..

Do I need a PIT file for the `dd` approach?

Comment: There's something called [Mobile Odin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.mobileodin.pro&hl=zh_CN), though I'm not sure if it's up-to-date enough to handle newer devices.

Answer (score 1):

**Important note:** Hey guys, thanks for the upvotes but this answer turned out  to **not work at all**.

The steps below don't break anything and this is why I *thought* I flashed modem/bootloader. You can use `dd` to make backups of the partitions below by swapping `of`/`if` but modem/bootloader won't be modified by the code I've posted..

In the end I had to fiddle with heimdall and boot the phone in download mode to actually flash the partitions.

---

*Original answer:*

In case anyone else wants to flash Bootloader/Modem and heimdall/fastboot/odin is not an option - this worked for me:

Extract/copy the files you need somewhere on your phone - e.g. with `adb push ./bl_modem/ /mnt/extSdCard/`, start a su-shell:

```
adb shell
> su
> cd /mnt/extSdCard/bl_modem/
```

then just flash the files with `dd`:

```
> dd if=NON-HLOS.bin  of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p1
> dd if=modem.bin     of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p2
> dd if=sbl1.mbn      of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3
> dd if=sdi.mbn       of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p5
> dd if=aboot.mbn     of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p7
> dd if=rpm.mbn       of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p8
> dd if=tz.mbn        of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p9
```

Important: the provided block device names only apply to Note4/N910F. Have a look at the links at `/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/` to find out yours.

I double checked these names by first making a copy with `dd` and comparing sizes. The sizes won't be equal to the sizes of the files you're going to flash but they should be *about* similar size.